# Complex queries in CouchDB across multiple types of documents

Tags: join, couchdb, cloudant

I'm relatively new to CouchDB (more specifically Cloudant if it matters) and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around something.

Assume the following (simplified) document examples:

```
{ "docType": "school", "_id": "school1", "state": "CA" }
{ "docType": "teacher", "_id": "teacher1", "age": "40", "school": "school1" }
```

I want to find all the teachers aged $age (eg. 40) in state $state (eg. CA).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problems are you having with your attempt?

Comment: I don't see anything in the query language so far that would help me do that. I've also been reading and playing with "views", which allows me to combine data, however it does not seem to allow to run queries on the result (besides startKey, endKey)

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. Every view query is across multiple documents. A query would be pretty worthless if it weren't.

Comment: I think the example is pretty straight forward. Given the 2 documents above. Can you write a query that gives me “all teachers aged 40, working at a school in state CA”? As you can see, the answer involves combining 2 documents.

Comment: Maybe as you imply the answer is pretty obvious. In which case please share it as an answer :)

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a join. Which is not "across multiple documents". It's "across multiple types of documents", which is a very different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Views only consider one document at a time; that is queries can't directly combine data from different documents. You can query across multiple fields in the same document using Cloudant Query. You can write a selector directly in the Cloudant dashboard. Something like

```
"selector": {
  "age": {
    "$gte": 40
  },
  "state": {
    "$eq": "CA"
  }
}
```

See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/tutorials?topic=cloudant-creating-an-ibm-cloudant-query

with the full reference here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/tutorials?topic=cloudant-query

You could also use a so-called linked document to emulate basic joins, as outlined in the CouchDB docs https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html

Comment: Doesn’t this assume that both age and state are in the same document? Per the example I gave, they are in 2 separate documents ...

Comment: That can't be done, sorry. No joins. Denormalise your model, or you need multiple  queries and client-side work.

Comment: That’s the feeling I’m getting indeed, but no one is giving me a definite answer. If you are sure of it, can you edit your answer explaining this?

Comment: By the way some comments mentioned “views”, but without explaining how it would solve the problem. Maybe you know about this ...

Comment: A linked document would go some part of the way (see edit) but really the problem is that you've already painted yourself into a relational-like corner with your example documents. Your data structures basically stipulate that queries need to combine documents, thus working against the grain of Cloudant/CouchDB.